# In Racket, is a list an array?

Tags: arrays, racket

From what I learned about arrays, it seems that lists in Racket may fit the definition.  Arrays need to be able to store different types of data and be ordered.  Lists in Racket fit these requirements.  However, arrays also need to be indexed, and I'm not sure lists in Racket fit this requirement.

Comment: It's easier to understand when reading "A list is a combination of pairs that creates a linked list". http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pairs.html?q=list#%28tech._list%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lists are not arrays, in that lists are not random-access. The Scheme analogue for arrays is *vectors*.

When you create a vector, you state upfront how large your vector will be (explicitly as an argument to `make-vector`, or implicitly based on how many arguments you call `vector` with, or implicitly, if you're using `list->vector`, based on the size of the list you're copying from). You can then read (`vector-ref`) and write (`vector-set!`) individual elements based on index.

Vectors cannot be resized; if you need a new size, you need to create a new vector and copy elements to it using `vector-copy` (if you're creating the new vector at the same time) or `vector-copy!` (if you're copying into a vector you created yourself).

---

In contrast, lists are simply zero or more cons cells that are chained together in a specific way, eventually pointing to the empty list. In particular, the empty list `()` is a list, and any cons cell where the `cdr` points to a list is a list. Because you have to chase down cons cells, there is no random access: to reach the nth element of a list, it takes time proportional to n (list indexing is O(n)).

In contrast, it takes roughly the same amount of time (if we ignore things like cache locality) to access any element of a vector (vector indexing is O(1)).